# What is your recommended workflow for Flutter null safety migration tool

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I am using the Flutter null safety migration tool.
What is your recommended workflow for null safety migration?

For example:

- Start at `main.dart` first and work your way out from there?
- Start with models or classes first?
- Start with screens first?
- Just go down the list as displayed by the null-migration tool?

Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was migrating with null safety this flow help me so much.

1. Start with models or classes first.
2. Then start with screens.
3. Then go down the list as displayed by the null-migration tool
   Just go down the list as displayed by the null-migration tool
4. Finally at main.dart

Comment: Zakaria, thank you for your reply. In following your recommendation, it seems to be working out better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to use a tool like [lakos](https://pub.dev/packages/lakos) to analyze the internal dependencies of the classes and source files.

The I would start converting to null safety at the leaves of the dependency tree, using info from the null safety-migration tool.